# How would I use fgets to not read in spaces

Tags: c

I am comparing two files line by line and was wondering if there was a way to get fgets not to read in spaces. For example, if one file has

```
  hello world
```

and another file had

```
hello       world
```

I want to ignore the first two spaces and the spaces in the middle and return that both these lines are equal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define BUFSIZE 1024 


int linecmp(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2);
int charcmp(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2);
int wordcmp(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
size_t i;
FILE *fp1;
FILE *fp2;

fp1 = fopen("input.txt", "rb+");
fp2 = fopen("input2.txt", "rb+");



printf("%d",linecmp(fp1, fp2));


return 0;
}

int linecmp(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2)
{
char line[BUFSIZE];
char line2 [BUFSIZE];
size_t linecount = 0;
size_t linecount2 = 0;

/*reads from first file pointer*/
while(fgets(line,BUFSIZE, fp1))
{   
    ;
}
/*reads from second file pointer*/
while(fgets(line2,BUFSIZE, fp2))
{
    ;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, the `fgets` function has no such capability. You have to remove the spaces yourself.

But perhaps not *all* the spaces.  For the purpose of your assignment, should "hello world" be considered a match with "helloworld"?  If not, you might need to remove all leading
and trailing whitespace, but treat interior whitespace with a bit more care -- perhaps
replacing a run of whitespace characters with a single blank before doing the comparison.

Comment: I have thought of something like that, but i was thinking of using sscanf to skip the spaces, but if i do a "%s" conversion specifier to something like "hello[SPACE][SPACE]world", it just reads "hello"

Comment: @user: The problem with sscanf is that you generally won't know how many "words" there are in the line.  And if you try to use sscanf in a loop to get one word at a time, there's no way to tell how many spaces it skipped over, so where would you start looking for the next word?  Once you read in the line, you're probably going to need to go through it character by character, looking for space vs. non-space, and building a new string that only has the characters you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

How about using <strike>scanf()</strike> sscanf() with "%s" to skip whitespace ?

Comment: Yeah i tried with sscanf but if i got the phrase "hello   world" it just reads "hello"

Comment: You need to keep doing a sscanf() till you reach the end of the line. Your sscanf() would effectively be in a loop.